# Apache doesn't work correctly on another branch

Tags: git, apache

I have a problem with running project locally. On branch master everything is fine, a project is compiled well. But when I'm switching branch I have js errors in console `"Cannot read property 'places' of undefined".` It isn't a problem with this branch, because on another computer is working correctly. Seems like apache doesn't see all code from another branch. Is it possible? How can I fix it?

My configuration:

- Apache/2.4.37
- macOS Mojave 10.14
- Git 2.17.1

Comment: Sorry, but it is completely unclear what you are talking about.

Comment: Apache seems irrelevant here. You'll have to debug your JS in browser and find where it fails, but ... Apache?! More probably your JS files or HTML structure are different on different branches.

Comment: @RomainValeri, so why on another computer everything on another branch is fine?! Code is exactly the same, no local changes, so I think it isn't problem with code.

Comment: are all versions of everything involved the same on each computer?